# 7z from bash script won't exclude directories

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-script

I've encountered with kinda strange behaviour of 7z (or bash, I don't know yet.).
With the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/user  -type f -name "*.pdf" | cut -c 10- > /home/user/exclude_list2.lst;
lst1=" -x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' "
command=$(/usr/bin/7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user);
$command
```

also, the last two lines can be easily substituted with single line:

```
/usr/bin/7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user
```

I've also tried :

```
command="/usr/bin/7z a  $lst1  -v2048M arch0.7z /home/dh ;"
```

I receive a 'arch0.7z' file, but folders .config and .cache are being included still, while:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/user  -type f -name "*.pdf" | cut -c 10- > /home/user/exclude_list2.lst;
/usr/bin/7z a -x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user ;"
```

generates a file with properly excluded folders.

So, I wonder, what is the difference between the line expanded from variable:

```
/usr/bin/7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user
```

and the one I've typed as is:

```
 /usr/bin/7z a -x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user
```

Is there any reason for such significant changes in 7z workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original form

```
command=$(/usr/bin/7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user);
$command
```

will mean that `$command` contains the *output* of the 7zip run, as `var=$(...)` will store the output of a command into the variable.

Therefore,

```
/usr/bin/7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/user
```

is a not a substitution, but a correction of the error in the script.

Anyway, to the real issue.

If you run the variable assignment in the shell, you will notice the following:

```
$ lst1=" -x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' "
-bash: !'*.config/*': event not found
```

So, you have an error in this line, as the shell will do variable substitution etc. when double quotes `"..."` are used. The problematic item is the `!`, as it used by bash to refer to previous commands in its history. Use single quotes instead: `'...'`

```
$ lst1=' -x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' '
$ echo $lst1
-x@/home/user/exclude_list2.lst -xr!*.config/* -xr!*.cache/*
```

Answer (score 0):

That's something I wasn't expecting for.

```
lst1=' -xr@/home/me/exclude_list2.lst -xr!'*.config/*' -xr!'*.cache/*' -xr!'*.local/*' '
7z a $lst1 -v2048M arch0.7z /home/me
```

do the trick, while I was thinking that single quote in *-xr!'*.config/*'* will end the variable assignment,  it actually works as a part of argument.
Also, works perfectly if my variable is an array.

By the way, escaping with "!" won't work, 7z says "Error: Incorrect command line" for it.